# What are the limits of vagueness and obviousness in questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

One of my first questions was successful ([Link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114431/what-flies-when-its-born-lies-while-its-alive-and-runs-when-its-dead)), but was closed as:

> "This question may invite speculative answers, as the question is not fully defined. The validity of some answers may be based upon opinion. Good questions for this site have a limited number of objectively correct answers."

What is this limit, and why is speculation bad for the site?

Then another one of my questions ([Link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115237/rhyming-riddle-born-from-gods-of-primordial-prowess)) was admittedly very obvious, and was voted to close.
So what is the limit for too much obviousness and too much vagueness, in a question?